# Image from database doesn't load PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, base64

I am trying to load an image stored in a blob field in mysql database. All other fields connected to user are working.

The fetch to the database for the image specifically is:

```
public function singleIMG(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

The query function in my user model is:

```
public function getJobImg($ekspert_id){
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM eksperti WHERE id = :id");

    $this->db->bind(':id', $ekspert_id);

    $row = $this->db->singleIMG();
    extract($row);
    return $row;
}
```

I fetch the data in my controller:

```
$template->img = $job->getJobImg($job_id);
```

Finally, it doesn't load the view:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($img['profile_img']).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail">
```

Could you please find my mistake?

Comment: What have you done so far to debug this? Have you checked the HTML output this creates? Have you made a debug output of $img in the template to verify it actually contains what you assumed it does? Is the `<img src="..." …>` even dynamically output inside a PHP code block to begin with? (Or have you just output the _static text_ `<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($img['profile_img']).'" …` in that place?)

Comment: I have tried to output it just as a string and it does fetch the blob object from the database, but when i encode it in the browser console i get a ERR_INVALID_URL error

Comment: Please show the whole line from your template as the single and double quotes dont seem to make sense to me

Comment: Did you base64_encod the image BEFORE adding it to your database?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, I was following a tutorial and there the guy used addslashes() method before inserting the file to database. Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Unless you encode the image before storing, it will likely get corrupted in the store process. Images have all sorts of internal data structures that can be confused as end of file. Anyway if you added slashes on store one would expect you to remove them before the image would be correct anyway. But that too may correupt the images file format as well

Answer (score 0):

You didn't have the base64_encode in `<?php ?>` tags, so it was just showing as the text `base64_encode($img['profile_img']);`

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64, <?php echo base64_encode($img['profile_img']); ?>" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail">
```

should work. I'm unfamiliar with using bas64 as an image, so i'm not sure if you'd need to write it like this:

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'<?php echo base64_encode($img['profile_img']); ?>'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail">
```

or if it would work sans-single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Used the `base64_encode()` before adding the image to the database, and removed the encode function when rendering the image, kept the `data:image/jpg;base64` inside the html tag.